# ComboBox Binding Collection and Selected Property

Tags: wpf, combobox

**Why doesn't #2 work?** (It seems like most examples say to do this).

```
#1(works)<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Marker.ReadOnlyContentRegions}" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Marker.SelectedRegion}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding
                                        Marker.SelectedRegion.UniqueId,    Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  SelectedValuePath="UniqueId" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Label" />

#2(doesn't work)<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Marker.ReadOnlyContentRegions}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Marker.SelectedRegion.UniqueId,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedValuePath="UniqueId" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Label" />
```

This is the class that contains the objects that should be databound.
class...

```
    public CancellableObservableCollection<InvisibleContentMarkerBase>       
        ReadOnlyContentRegions
    {
        get { return
             CancellableObservableCollection<InvisibleContentMarkerBase>)
                         GetValue(ReadOnlyContentRegionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ReadOnlyContentRegionsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadOnlyContentRegionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ReadOnlyContentRegions",  
           typeof(CancellableObservableCollection<InvisibleContentMarkerBase>), 
           typeof(TargetedContentMarker), new UIPropertyMetadata(null);

    public InvisibleContentMarkerBase SelectedRegion
    {
        get { return (InvisibleContentMarkerBase)GetValue(SelectedRegionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedRegionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedRegionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedRegion", 
            typeof(InvisibleContentMarkerBase), typeof(TargetedContentMarker), new 
            UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

...// end of class

Comment: is the `class` code in a control class or a data class?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't set both the `SelectedItem` and the `SelectedValue`

They both set the exact same property, so when you set both only one value will actually get used

When you set `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue`, you are setting the selected item by value. The `SelectedValuePath` tells WPF what property on objects in the collection is the `Id` field, and `SelectedValue` tells WPF to set the selected item to the value that is equal to `SelectedValue`.

`SelectedItem` simply tells WPF to select the item in the collection that exactly matches the `SelectedItem` object. Note that this comparison is by reference, so if the `SelectedItem` is a class that doesn't point to the exact same reference in memory as one of the objects in the `ItemsSource`, it won't evaluate the two objects as the same and won't set the item as Selected

So in short, either get rid of the `SelectedItem` binding and just use `SelectedValue`/`SelectedValuePath`, or remove `SelectedValue`/`SelectedValuePath` and ensure that the object bound in `SelectedItem` refers to the exact same object in memory as the copy in the `ItemsSource`.

If you really can't reference that object, and insist on using `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`, you could also [overwrite the .Equals() on your class](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/) so it returns true if the data is equal, regardless of if the memory reference is the same. I prefer to avoid this since this changes the functionality of any instances of this class, but wanted to let you know that option is available.

Comment: Well, I have a class that derives from dependencyobject, which seals Equals which I wanted to override. There seems to be a condition where the selectedItem references are lost in my code and thus the selecteed item, too. So, what you are saying is that if I remove the selectedValuePath and SelectedValue from my code the binding should still work (although it doesn't ensure that the selectedItem object is a reference to the correct object).

Comment: @jwize Yes, WPF will only use one of `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem`. So either remove `SelectedValue` and ensure that `SelectedItem` points to an object that exists in the `ItemsSource`, or remove `SelectedItem` and set your object by `SelectedValue`

Comment: That still doesn't answer the concern about the dependency derived object, so I am still stuck. And the example doesn't work for me without selectedValue / SelectedValuePath. Maybe there is something wrong with my binding then?

Comment: @jwize Sounds like it. I'd suggest using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see what your `DataContext` is on the ComboBox, then you can make sure it has a property called `Marker.SelectedRegion` that points to the same object in memory as one of the items in `Marker.ReadOnlyContentRegions`

Comment: So, I guess that means there isn't a solution for DependencyObjects for overriding the Equals method (which would be a much simpler solution)?

Comment: @jwize I don't think so. Why is your data model inheriting from `DependencyObject` anyways? I think that's typically a class used for UI components that participate in the dependency property system